# Converting an ONNX model to TensorFlow produces a ValueError, how do I resolve it?

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow.js

[ PyTorch's KoBERT model has been converted to ONNX model. ]
[ Error when converting ONNX model to Tensorflow model. ]

onnx_model = onnx.load('onnx1.onnx')

tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)
tf_rep.export_graph('tensorModel.pb')

### => An error occurs when the code is executed.

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend_tf_module.py", line 99, in __call__  *
    output_ops = self.backend._onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op(onnx_node,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py", line 347, in _onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op  *
    return handler.handle(node, tensor_dict=tensor_dict, strict=strict)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/handler.py", line 59, in handle  *
    return ver_handle(node, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/backend/slice.py", line 140, in version_11  *
    return cls.version_10(node, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/backend/slice.py", line 109, in version_10  *
    dense_ends = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(sparse_indices, ends_final,

ValueError: Shape (1, 1) must have rank 1
```

I am modifying input_name and ouput_name to solve the error but it is not solving.